# how to break out of .each() iteration

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Nested jQuery.each() - continue/break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267508/nested-jquery-each-continue-break)

Here is my code:

```
var steps = $("div#f");
steps.each(function () {
    var s = $(this);
    var cs = $(this).find(".Cm");
    cs.each(function () {
        var tc = $(this);
        var err = tc.attr("h");
        if (err == false) {
            this.c = err;//this.c is a global variable
            return this.c;
            break;//here is where the error is being thrown
        }
        else {
            this.c =  {"Eval": err, "S": s, "Cm": tc};
            return this.c;
        }
    });
});
```

I'm using an `.each()` iteration to collect values. I thought it functioned like a loop so i thought id use a `break` statement to break out. This is throwing an "illegal" error. Does anyone know how to break out of an `each` iteration?

Comment: RTFM: http://api.jquery.com/each/ : "We can stop the loop from within the callback function by returning false."

Comment: return false would work.

Comment: Marat, TFM doesn't really explain why very thoroughly.  Nice positive attitude though, good luck with that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

use `return false`. Take a look at this resource: http://gavinroy.com/jquery-tip-how-to-break-out-of-each

Comment: Or the [official docs](http://api.jquery.com/each/).

Answer (score 4):

To break out of `.each()`, simply use `return false;`

Take a look at the [jQuery `.each()` docs](http://api.jquery.com/each/) for more information.

Here's an example, given in the docs:

```
$("button").click(function() {
    $("div").each(function(index, domEle) {
        // domEle == this
        $(domEle).css("backgroundColor", "yellow");
        if ($(this).is("#stop")) {
            $("span").text("Stopped at div index #" + index);
            return false; //Equivalent to break;
        }
    });
});​
```

Comment: Really? a -1 for the correct answer, link to the docs, and example code? Care to explain?

Answer (score 1):

its a function, you can just `return false` to `break` out of the loop altogether or,  if you want something that works like the `continue` statement,  you can `return true`

```
each( function() 
{
   if ( someCondition ) return true; // same as continue;
   if ( someOtherCondition) return false; // same as break;
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not really in a for-each loop, so a break doesn't make sense.  It's actually a function that is being called each time, so you need to return from that function and tell jQuery to stop calling.

Return false instead, and that should break out of the loop.