# how to break out from outer each loop

Tags: jquery

I have the following scenario:

```
$.each(array, function() {
    ...
    $.each(array1, function() {
        if condition () { }
    });
});
```

How can I break out of outer `each` loop when my condition evaluates to true inside the inner `each` loop?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nested jQuery.each() - continue/break](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267508/nested-jquery-each-continue-break)

Comment: not its not, i only have to go with each loops not for loops.

Comment: Look at some of the other answers there (like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3267627/535871)); they present solutions that maintain the use of `$.each`.

Comment: did u really think i would use the approach of throwing exceptions or using break..i want my code readable. the answer which is given below by Codesleuth solves my problem.

Comment: The answer I linked to in my comment is essentially identical to that by Codesleuth.

Comment: With all due respect Mr. ted, question is same to the one you have linked, but the asnwers are not as i had expected. They are suggesting to use for loops, throw exceptions, use break statements which i dont want. Again, answer given by Codesleuth  makes sense for me here.

Comment: Did you look at the link in my second comment (a different answer to the same question)? That's the one that matches Codesleuth's.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
$.each(array, function() {
    var flag = true;

    $.each(array1, function() {
        if (condition) {
            flag = false;
            return false;
        }
    });

    return flag;
});
```

Comment: If you reverse the sense of `flag` (so it is `true` when you want to continue the outer loop), then you can replace the last statement with `return flag;` (avoiding the `if` test).

Comment: Thanks Codesleuth, I'm going to mark it as answer as soon as stackoverflow time limit gets over.

Answer (score 5):

Set a value to test in the outer loop to exit

```
$.each(array, function() {
    var exit = false;
    $.each(array1, function() {
        if ( condition ) { 
           exit = true;
           return false;
        }
    }
    if (exit){
        return false;
    }
}
```