# How to exit to main loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

these loops are iterating through arrays.

```
arrayFinalValues = [];
    $(arrayAccessRightID).each(function (i, val) {
        $(arrayNodeID).each(function (j, val1) {
            arrayFinalValues.push(val);
            arrayFinalValues.push(val1);
            $(arraySelectedValues).each(function (k, val2) {
                arrayFinalValues.push(val2);
                if (arrayFinalValues.length % 6 == 0)
                    return false;
            });
        });
    });
```

in the inner most loop when six elements are entered i want again to start from the outermost loop and in the inner most loop the index should start from next 4th element i.e., i want to in the structure 1,1,T,T,F,F,1,2,F,F,F,F. and so on. that is in the inner most loop the index should start from next elements.when i use return false in inner most loop it again starts with 0.i tried labels but its now working.

Comment: this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564818/how-to-break-2-loops-in-javascript ?

Comment: @PratikJoshi: `break` has no effect on jQuery's `each`. Putting it anywhere in the OP's quoted code would be a syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12161949/1182982)

```
$(arrayAccessRightID).each(function (i, val) {
    var shouldExit = true;
    $(arrayNodeID).each(function (j, val1) {
        arrayFinalValues.push(val);
        arrayFinalValues.push(val1);
        $(arraySelectedValues).each(function (k, val2) {
            arrayFinalValues.push(val2);
            if (arrayFinalValues.length % 6 == 0)
            {
              shouldExit = false;
              return shouldExit;
            }
        });
        return shouldExit;
    });
    return shouldExit;
});
```

Comment: I'm not saying you *copied* it (from me, I mean), don't get the wrong idea. I'm just saying that now that's it's corrected, it's redundant rather than incorrect.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder here is the post I borrowed the code from : http://stackoverflow.com/a/12161949/1182982

Comment: I thought you actually Answered yourself ,you just googled it :(

Comment: Nice catch on the fact there are *three* loops. I didn't notice that.

Comment: the solution is not working.already googled but not found anything helpful :(

Comment: Add a breakpoint and find out where its not working and post your finding here. Simply telling its not working wont make us know what is not working.