# unable to break out of jquery each loop

Tags: jquery, return, iteration, each

I have a nested loop written in jquery and return false inside my child loop keeps appending the same text to the parent row. My code,

```
$('#listingProducts ul.msRows li.msFullfillment').each(function(index) {                    
    if(typeof $('#hfOrd'+index).val() != 'undefined'){
        var $this = $(this);
        var orderId = $('#hfOrd'+index).val();                      
        // repainting logic
        $('body').append(data);
        $('#ajaxProducts ul.displayPoints li').each(function(index){
            var $child = $(this);
            if(typeof $('#hfAjaxOrderId'+index).val() != 'undefined'){
                var ajaxOrderId = $('#hfAjaxOrderId'+index).val();
                //alert(orderId+' '+ ' '+ajaxOrderId);
                if(ajaxOrderId === orderId){
                    // replace the div here..
                    var anchorText = $child.find("#pointsLineAjax .redeem").text();     
                    $this.find("#pointsLine .redeem").text(anchorText);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });

    }
});
```

Return false inside child loop doesnt go back to the parent. That doesnt seem to write it to the corresponding row. What am i missing here..

Comment: What is `$('#hfOrd'+index).val()`?

Comment: create a fiddle to check what is going on.

Comment: @ling.s its the orderid in the existing row and i am comparing with the row returned from ajax which has orderid if both are same i am replacing the text.

Comment: Why you are using +index?

Comment: Because i am generating my ids like that while rendering

Comment: @ling can you please help?

Comment: Check `alert($('#hfOrd'+index).val());` and see what it shows. can you post it in http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3267627/661447 You don't need `if(typeof $('#hfOrd'+index).val() != 'undefined')`, just do `if($('#hfOrd'+index).length)`

Comment: @ling.s That is correct syntax, you would essentially get `$('#hfOrd1').val()`, `$('#hfOrd2').val()` etc

Comment: @ling.s That is what it what it would equate to, it is just appending text to text to generate a selector: http://jsfiddle.net/jammykam/MBLrM/

Comment: @coderman I think `if(ajaxOrderId === orderId)` is always false because they are pointing different objects. try `==`

Answer (score 2):

Returning `false` only breaks out of the inner loop in a jQuery loop, there is a good explanation for the reason [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3267627/661447).

> The problem here is that while you can return false from within the
>   .each callback, the .each function itself returns the jQuery object.
>   So you have to return a false at both levels to stop the iteration of
>   the loop. Also since there is not way to know if the inner .each found
>   a match or not, we will have to use a shared variable using a closure
>   that gets updated.

Try the following:

```
$('#listingProducts ul.msRows li.msFullfillment').each(function(index) {                    
    var continueLoop = true;
    if($('#hfOrd'+index).length){
        var $this = $(this);
        var orderId = $('#hfOrd'+index).val();                      
        // repainting logic
        $('body').append(data);
        $('#ajaxProducts ul.displayPoints li').each(function(index){
            var $child = $(this);
            if($('#hfAjaxOrderId'+index).length){
                var ajaxOrderId = $('#hfAjaxOrderId'+index).val();
                //alert(orderId+' '+ ' '+ajaxOrderId);
                if(ajaxOrderId === orderId){
                    // replace the div here..
                    var anchorText = $child.find("#pointsLineAjax .redeem").text();     
                    $this.find("#pointsLine .redeem").text(anchorText);
                    continueLoop = false;
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    };
    return continueLoop;
});
```